# Linked lists, program in C

Tags: c, linked-list, analysis, lexical-analysis

I write a program which will analyze code in pascal. I've finished work with text and now I have to save my results in linked lists and I have any concept how to do it. In my program I have following elements:

```
variables(name, type)
constants(name)
typedef(name and components)
procedures(local variables, constants and types)
function (its var, const and types)
```

To my mind creating 5 lists won't be efficient solution. Can you give me a tip how to create list for these elements with different quantity of components?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "efficient".

If you want to have all the different elements in the same list, you will need to add type information to the elements, and of course spend time filtering out all the wrong elements when looking for something.

It would seem more efficient, then, to have separate collections of various types of element.

You should do something like:

```
typedef struct Element Element;

struct Element {
  Element     *next;
};

typedef struct {
  char *name;
  VariableType type;
} ElementVariable;

/* ... and so on */
```

Then you can have various linked list headers:

```
ElementVariable *variables;
ElementConstant *constants;
```

Since each `ElementXXX` type begins with an `Element`, you can write fairly generic linked-list code to deal with all the different types.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want to do with the lists, but here's an idea: Create a tree where *siblings* act like the regular `next` item in the liked list and where *children* provide additional information like entries of compound types or function parameters.

So the struct would look something like this:

```
struct Entity {
    const char *id;
    enum Type type;
    char is_const;
    char is_var;
    /* ... whatever ... */
    struct Entity *next;
    struct Entity *child;
};
```

So if you have

```
var x: integer;
procedure proc(var res: integer, x, y: integer); forward;
type date = record
    dd, mm, yy: integer;;
end;
```

your tree would look like this:

```
[var x: integer]
  |
[proc: procedure]     ->  [var res: integer]
  |                         |
  |                       [x: integer]
  |                         |
  |                       [y: integer]
  |
[type date: record]   ->  [dd: integer]
                            |
                          [mm: integer]
                            |
                          [yy: integer]
```

Here, the arrow `->` denotes children and the vertical bar `|` siblings or just the next item in the list.

The elements at the left form your primary list, that include your first-level (global scope) symbols. The next level means the scope of the parent element. For example `dd` is only known inside the record `date`. This is essentially a multi-level linked list that is easy to expand for arbitrary numbers of function arguments or record entries.

Answer (score 0):

5 lists aren't necessarily inefficient unless you want to search them all for a name,  or something.

An alternative is to make a generic way of storing all your info in one list. You could enumerate what you're storing.